# Seamless tiling with TexturePacker and Marmalade/IwGX

Tags: rendering, tiles, marmalade, texture-atlas

I'm looking for a way to get seamless tiling working, where the tiles are sprites off a TexturePacker sprite sheet, and the rendering is done with Marmalade's IwGX's streams. I also need to render the tiles in multiple scales at the same time.

Even with TP settings "reduce border artifacts: off" and "inner padding: 0", there are very noticeable, pixel-wide gaps between the tiles. If I move the tiles close together, they look fine at a scale of 1, but anything smaller or larger yields gaps.

If I use one tile per texture, I get no gaps, but it means that I either can't have a variety, or each tile will take one draw call + material switching, which is not only slow, but brings the gaps back.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting "extrude: 1" in TexturePacker, then `CIwMaterial::ALPHA_NONE`/`DEFAULT` for the alpha mode of the material that the sprites are rendered off, solves the problem.